# Samsung Galaxy S8 not recognised by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, samsung-galaxy

I am trying to use my Galaxy S8 with android studio as an external device but it seems like my Mac cannot recognize it.

- I have developer mode and USB debugging enabled
- ADB drivers are installed, but when I run ADB devices on terminal it does not display anything
- I tried to restart the ADB server several times but it does not work anyway
- I tried on a different Mac and on a Windows computer - same problem-
- I tried all the previous solutions with a different USB cable - same problem-
- I installed SmartSwitch, but also this program does not recognize my device, same for AFT, I also deleted one of the two and tried singularly, but as always, it does not work.

Basically it seems that the phone can only be charged via usb, but I have no reason to believe that the usb port might be damaged.

Comment: Make sure the connection mode is MTP or whatever it's called; if it's set to charging, the only thing you can do is charge.

Comment: It is already on MTP, I have tried also this

Comment: maybe you should ask your question in https://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 10):

I solved this problem downloading [this driver from the oficial Samsung page](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows). After install it, the whole drivers will re-install again. Besides, make sure you have enabled the Debugging mode and try to run again. I hope this helps.

Comment: This is only for Windows :(

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. An OTA update had turned off developer mode and I hadn't realized it.

Settings → Developer options → USB debugging → (on)

resolved it for me.

Answer (score 5):

Me too I had same issue (Mac + samsung s8), I tried a lot of things, and then it worked :

1. Unplug your Android Device
2. Disable the USB debugging
3. Re-enable and plug (or maybe, plug and re-enable, can't remember)

Answer (score -1):

Me too I had same issue (Mac + samsung s8), I followed this way:

1. Turn on development mode on samsung s8, [follow instructions](https://thedroidguy.com/2019/06/enable-developer-options-samsung-galaxy-s8-enable-usb-debugging-1074660).
2. Allow usb debugging.

It worked.